Simple controller-based launcher for Linux
I have a brother with intellectual disabilities, and I wanted to set up a PC for him to play some games on. I wanted to get him a mix of emulated games and native games, but most of the launchers I know of, like Retroarch or Emulation Station, are emulator based, and are also a little bit complicated for him. I really just need something that provides a menu of .desktop files that he can pick with a gamepad. What would be a good option for that?

You can add external games to Steam, and Steam Big Picture mode has pretty good controller support.
